# Separate different failures when using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using `fetch` to make requests to the backend of my application, which uses an OAuth authentication provider.

When the session expires, the fetch request is redirected to the authentication provider, causing it to fail because of a CORS error (which I cannot change).

In this case, `fetch` throws a `TypeError: failed to fetch`.
Unfortunately, I am also getting a `TypeError: failed to fetch`, when the network is down or the request times out for another reason.

How can I reliably discriminate between these failure modes?

I have not found any useful properties on the thrown TypeError, that would allow these failures to be distinguished.

Comment: use response code;

Comment: Why would you deliberately cause a CORS error? Don't redirect the `fetch` request itself, respond with a "session expired" status instead.

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A The response object is not available because fetch throws an error.

Comment: @Bergi the redirect is part of the setup of the system that I am working in and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Palle Then you're set up for failure

Comment: @Bergi I wish I could change this but I unfortunately cannot. This is a system that has been in place before me and that includes many components, which are out of my reach (including the gateway that handles authentication and causes the redirect). That's why I need to discriminate between these failure modes and why I don't have another way of doing this.

Comment: exactly; if there is no response code, it means that request didn't reach the server for some reason

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A yes but that would also be the case if the network was down. I want to distinguish these two failure modes.

Comment: you can't. due to security purposes. cors error will ONLY shown in console. no way to get it on javascript code

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A it is acceptable for me to know that I got a redirection response. I don't need to exactly know, where it got redirected to. I was able to resolve this by using `{redirect: "manual"}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to catch redirects using the `redirect: "manual"` option.

```
fetch(url, {redirect: "manual"})
```

While it is not possible to catch the redirection URL for security purposes, this is an acceptable resolution for me at this point.